# Go-lang Testing, What is the meaning of Parallel Setting on Benchmark?

Tags: testing, go

In https://golang.org/pkg/testing/ described that we can use `testing.B.RunParallel()` function to run benchmark in a *parallel setting*. I tried to write simple testing code:

```
func BenchmarkFunctionSome(b *testing.B) {

    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        SomeFunction()
    }
}
```

and then i changed it to use `RunParallel()`

```
func BenchmarkFunctionSome(b *testing.B) {

    b.RunParallel(func(pb *testing.PB) {
        for pb.Next() {
            SomeFunction()
        }
    })
}
```

And the one which used `RunParallel()` is slower than the first benchmark.

Actually what is the meaning of *parallel setting* in benchmarking? Why it became slower if i used `RunParallel()` ?

Comment: Its meaning is described in the godoc for the RunParallel method: https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#B.RunParallel . Is there something specifically you don't understand about it?

Comment: Why its slower when we use RunParallel? Without it i got 0.3x ns/op but with RunParallel i got 1.1x ns/op. How this parallel benchmark works?

Comment: If you run the benchmark in parallel each go routine will be "competing" with each other. So it will be slightly slower

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The for loop in the first benchmark has all tests run sequentially, one at a time, and the performance is the time divided by iterations.

The RunParallel benchmark divides the iterations among available threads. The performance is calculated similarly, probably averaging each group. The point of this is that several (exact # based upon your GOMAXPROCS setting) test iterations are run concurrently. This is especially helpful in testing functions with shared resources and locking, which may run fine solo but introduce performance issues when run concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whats there inside

```
SomeFunction()
```

If its just an empty function or a simple calculation, serial benchmark will be faster. But if it's a heavy computation or IO,

```
RunParallel()
```

benchmark will be faster.